# basic java script json child array decoding

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, twitter

I have been teaching myself some basic javascript the last couple of days and playing with google scripting as well as the twitter api and have come a bit unstuck on something that should probably be quite easy!

For sake of easierness of typing so my return from twitter api looks like this

```
[id:1
connections: "NONE"
],

[id:2
connections: ["following", "followed_by"]
]
```

What I am trying to do is find out out if the key 'following' exists for user 2, but I am really struggling!

The twitter api docs show an examples json as

```
[
  {
    "name": "Taylor Singletary",
    "id_str": "819797",
    "id": 819797,
    "connections": [
      "none"
    ],
    "screen_name": "episod"
  },
  {
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "id": 6253282,
    "connections": [
      "following",
      "followed_by"
    ],
    "screen_name": "twitterapi"
  }
]
```

Can any point me in the correct direction?, how do I find out if following exists?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand, you want to check of the second element in array has the value 'following' in connections array?

Comment: Hi juvian, that is correct, however if it doesnt exist then the array just reads "connections":["followed_by"], is there a way to count the results?

Comment: How to evaluate and how to handle array in json using javascript are mentioned in this useful and genuine link - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connections: ["following", "followed_by"]` is an `array`. To check if an array contains a special value you can use `indexOf()`:

```
var a = [1, 2, "three", 44];
a.indexOf(1); // 0
a.indexOf(2); // 1
a.indexOf("three"); // 2
a.indexOf(22); // -1
```

So to check if "following" is in the array:

```
if (connections.indexOf("following") !== -1) {
  // yeah!
} else {
  // doh!
}
```

To count the objects in your example which have "following":

```
var o = [
  {
    "name": "Taylor Singletary",
    "id_str": "819797",
    "id": 819797,
    "connections": [
      "none"
    ],
    "screen_name": "episod"
  },
  {
    "name": "Twitter API",
    "id_str": "6253282",
    "id": 6253282,
    "connections": [
      "following",
      "followed_by"
    ],
  "screen_name": "twitterapi"
  }
];

var withFollowing = o.filter(
  function (i) {
    return i.connections.indexOf("following") !== -1;
  }
);
// filter() returns a new array
// this new array has only the elements for which the function returns true

console.log(withFollowing.lenght);
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks that really helped, kudos for the range of possibilities as well!